# Vector Asset Studio is importing colorful .svg file as black and white

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, vector-graphics

I'm using the instructions found [here, from Google](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html) to use the new option (March 2016) to import .svg files into drawable instead of .png files.

The problem I have is that the file gets imported as black and white, even though the file has many colors.

Here's an image of the .svg file, as read by Google Chrome:
[image]

This same file, is then read like this by the Vector Asset Studio:
[image]
[image]

And in the app, the image shows up as black and white.

Any idea of why this is happening?

The .svg file is getting generated on Adobe PhotoShop Creative Cloud, and I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 on Mac.

Thank you!

**EDIT: added [link to .svg file I'm using](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzJXCzstEQa4ZWNVbGdUV1M3OWs/view?usp=sharing) for this question.**

Comment: Does the image have external CSS? Does Vector Asst Studio support external CSS?

Comment: Ummm. I don't know the answer to either question. This is coming to me from our design team. Any idea where I should have them check for the external css in Photoshop?

Comment: Add the file to the question.

Comment: There's no external CSS in that file. I don't know why it doesn't display, it should work. I suggest you take this up with Vector Asset Studio's bugtracker wherever that it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I also had the same problem but after digging internet
finally found the solution, here it is:-

After getting done with illustrator designing

1) Go to File --> Save As ---> Window Dialog box Opens--> type name of svg 
--->Click Save

2) **Now it shows SVG Options dialog box ---> At bottom left click More Options ---> In CSS Properties dropdown ---> Select Presentation Attributes**

this setting makes svg compatible code for android import with colors !!

Sorry for making this answer elaborate ... did this for those who are beginners

Comment: This is the answer, everyone. Thanks, Vibhore.

Comment: Do you know how can I save the file on Inkscape?

Comment: For those using "Export for Screens" in Illustrator (especially useful if you have many images to export), then you can achieve this by entering Advanced Settings (using the cog icon in the Export for Screen dialog), then under SVG, change "Styling" to "Inline Style".

Comment: Its works in Corel Draw too. the same option, select presentation attributes. 
thanks mate.

Answer (score 12):

Android Studio's SVG importer is somewhat limited.  It only handles very simple SVG files.  And I don't believe it supports the `<style>` element, or the `class` attribute.  So you will need to change the CSS to XML properties.

For example:

```
<path class="st0" d="M163.3,10.8c2.4-0.5,6.2-0.9,10-0.9c5.5,0,9,0.9,11.6,3.1c2.2,1.6,3.5,4.1,3.5,7.5c0,4.1-2.7,7.7-7.2,9.3v0.1
    c4,1,8.7,4.3,8.7,10.6c0,3.6-1.4,6.4-3.6,8.5c-3,2.7-7.7,4-14.6,4c-3.8,0-6.7-0.3-8.5-0.5V10.8z M168.8,28.1h5c5.8,0,9.2-3,9.2-7.1
    c0-5-3.8-6.9-9.3-6.9c-2.5,0-4,0.2-4.8,0.4V28.1z M168.8,48.4c1.1,0.2,2.6,0.3,4.6,0.3c5.7,0,10.9-2.1,10.9-8.2
    c0-5.8-5-8.2-10.9-8.2h-4.5V48.4z"/>
```

Will need to be changed to:

```
<path fill="#007299" d="M163.3,10.8c2.4-0.5,6.2-0.9,10-0.9c5.5,0,9,0.9,11.6,3.1c2.2,1.6,3.5,4.1,3.5,7.5c0,4.1-2.7,7.7-7.2,9.3v0.1
    c4,1,8.7,4.3,8.7,10.6c0,3.6-1.4,6.4-3.6,8.5c-3,2.7-7.7,4-14.6,4c-3.8,0-6.7-0.3-8.5-0.5V10.8z M168.8,28.1h5c5.8,0,9.2-3,9.2-7.1
    c0-5-3.8-6.9-9.3-6.9c-2.5,0-4,0.2-4.8,0.4V28.1z M168.8,48.4c1.1,0.2,2.6,0.3,4.6,0.3c5.7,0,10.9-2.1,10.9-8.2
    c0-5.8-5-8.2-10.9-8.2h-4.5V48.4z"/>
```

Etcetera for the rest of the `<path>` elements.

Comment: that is what I ended up doing, but it will obviously become a problem with more complex images that have even a few colors. Any idea if this works better on the beta of Android Studio 2.0?

Comment: In Inkscape you can save as "Optimized SVG", which gives the option to convert CSS styles to XML properties.  However it threw an error when I tried your file with it.

Comment: Haha, nice! My only issue on that would be that we get the files from the marketing department, and they only use adobe CC stuff. This file was actually created on Illustrator. Yes, I could convert it in Inkscape, but if the colors change a bit (or anything else changes) then I'm kind of responsible for that, even though the marketing people gave us the correct images.

Comment: My question got marked as duplicate for this but what about just black/white  svg's being imported as all black? Same story? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069272/imported-local-svg-vector-via-vector-asset-studio-is-all-black

Answer (score -1):

It's so simple
you can change your color directly from your svg xml after adding image to your project .

when you added image to your project; svg color must be like this :

```
android:fillColor="#000000"
```

just need to change to this :

```
android:fillColor="#b3ff856d"
```

just looking for android:fillColor